# Problem with mount directory to container from local host

Tags: image, docker, dockerfile, containers

I'm newibe to docker, I used a dockerfile to make a container when i try to run the next comment:

```
docker run --name ai --rm -it -v /C/AI_project/:/AI_project project:latest bash
```

it makes the container but with empty AI_project folder.I tried to edited this line a lot of times but it never copy the folder.
How to add a folder from local host to the container?

[here my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WNdc.png)

Comment: What data do you want to persist? What's the location in your host, and the desired location inside the container?

Comment: I want to add a folder from my computer to my container

Comment: i added picture

Answer (score 0):

If all that you want to do is copying a file from the host to the container, you can use [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/):

```
docker cp local.file container:/path/local.file
```

If you want to mount a host file on the container when starting the container, you should do something like:

```
docker run -v local.file:/path/local.file --name name image
```

Comment: hi,thanks for anser but i want to copy a all folder

Comment: @IgalIoffe Same holds for a folder.

Comment: and i get a empty folder

Comment: i added picture